# Schedule Jitterbit Data loader for Salesforce

Tags: schedule

I have  a requirement to export data from salesforce on regular basis.
**and for this:** 
I need to schedule my data export task and i have gone through the Schedule wizard of jitterbit but
one thing is not clear, 
suppose i schedule my task then do i need to run this software for lifetime like everyday or is there any service which triggers this jitterbit so that it can perform its task.

Comment: I don't think so. But for testing, you can schedule a half hourly export of the data. After first export, you can close/end the jitterbit and check if the export happens.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. Let me elaborate this: who's gonna monitor that activity if i close jitterbit.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. Let me elaborate this: Suppose I close the Jitterbit app and for the very next day who's gonna monitor that export activity since I have closed the Jitterbit already. I mean there should be something in the system who's gonna say hey jitterbit : time for the today exportation like there should be some **service** that keeps on running lifetime that triggers my jitterbit so that it can perform its everyday task.

Comment: The reason Why i am asking this is because for Scheduling Apex Data loader u need to create  a .bat file that runs its process file and handover that .bat file to our native windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: @ShaileshPatil please find my comments forgot to tag u :)

Comment: Hi Mohit.... Could you test with the scenario I have mentioned in my comment? Try it on half hourly basis and check if it still runs after closing the application. As per my understanding, your settings will be stored on the jitterbit cloud.

Answer (score 3):

With Jitterbit, you can chose the scheduling frequency as shown below. There's nothing else you  need to do.

[image]

Comment: I think what Mohit wants to understand is once he schedules can he uninstall the app without affecting the schedules.

Comment: Thanks For ur Response Amit and but this is not what i am asking.. i agree we have scheduled the jitterbit for daily Export but who's is going to perform my task if i close my jitterbit application. and whos gonna tell jiterbit to perform my activity. Does My cloud will take care of export activity if in case the desktop app is closed if yes then how its gonna put a file to my local directory.. I Hope U getting my question @AmitBangad

Comment: Once it has been scheduled with Jitterbit, the app takes care of it as long as it's running.

Comment: @GauravKheterpal Thanks but I scheduled my task on Saturday and it works on that day but on sunday this scheduled task didn't work. what could be the reason? Is there any background service present on our system that keeps on running all the time that monitors this scheduled task?? That's wht i want to enquire.

Answer (score 2):

Jitterbit needs a Service to run as well as the Application. You should be able to find the apps: Mac ("Jitterbit Cloud Data Loader Start Services" and "Jitterbit Cloud Data Loader Stop Services") Windows: (StartServices and StopServices) in the Jitterbit Cloud Data Loader folder in Program Files (x86). So long as the Service is running, the Application does not have to be open. If you are worried about the Services stopping, you can use something like Lingon or some combination of Automator and Calendar for the Mac or Task Scheduler or similar for Windows.